# Vue.js debounce scroll

Tags: javascript, vue.js, debouncing

I am trying to use the [debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce) package with a Vue.js `v-on:scroll` binding like so:

```
<div @scroll="debounce(onScrollMessages, 200)"></div>
```

The problem is that `debounce` actually returns the debounced function to be used, but binding the event this way will actually call `debounce(onScrollMessages, 200)` every scroll event, this means that the debounced function will be computed and **created every** scroll event.

The actual issue is that the `@scroll` will bind the event something like this:

```
onScroll: function () {
   debounce(onScrollMessages, 200);
}
```

But, in order for the debounced function to be computed only once it should bind the event something like this:

```
// Notice how now the scroll event calls directly the 
// debounced function returned by "debounce()", not the
// function that calls "debounce()"
onScroll: debounce(onScrollMessages, 200)
```

How can I bind the `@scroll` event to the function returned by `debounce()` and not to a function that calls `debounce()` every time?

Comment: Possible to create a fiddle of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually figured out the solution right after asking this question.

Before I was declaring the `debounce` function like so (just aliasing it so I have access to it inside the template):

```
methods: {
   debounce: debounceFromNPM
}
```

But I changed it to this and it works (don't alias the package "debounce", but the returned debounced function directly):

```
debounce: debounceFromNPM(function () {
  this.onScrollMessages();
}, 3000)
```

And changed the template to:

```
<div @scroll="debounce"></div>
```

Notice that if you are using `ES6` arrow function syntax, having the lexical `this` it won't work:

```
// THIS DOESN'T WORK AS `this` WILL BE UNDEFINED
debounce: debounceFromNPM(() => {
  this.onScrollMessages();
}, 3000)
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the last section! saved me lots of time. Can you explain why the ES6 syntax would lose `this`?

Comment: @trailing-slash Arrow functions have a `lexical` this, it means that you can not bind the `this` context for an arrow function, it will just have the same value as the parent closure, in this case the window because that's what triggers (calls the callback of) the scroll event.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to explain this to me.